# ViewPager and Scene Transitions

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, android-viewpager, material-design

I'm trying to make my app more modern.

I have a ViewPager with two fragments. One fragment is "static" while the other one change change into another fragment. So three fragments in total. A, B and C where A always is visible and either B or C is visible.

With Googles new Material design they peruse animations when moving between activities, but as far as I can see there is no such thing for fragments. Also, if I replaced my fragments with three activities there is no alternative to the ViewPager.

Am I just stuck in here, or is there a way to animate the transition from fragment B to fragment C ? I am willing to do large rewrites of the UI, but no change the interface from a user perspective.

Comment: You can set standard or custom transition animations on `FragmentTransactions`.